# How to extract a substring after a particular pattern in Java using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

This is the input string xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [30/Oct/2020:22:39:54 +0000] --
I want to find date from this particular String i.e.
How I suppose to get this Value
I want to find pattern "- - [" and want to escape first backslash "/".

I tried below code

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*)- - "["").matcher(data);
 if(matcher.find()){
    String date = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(date);
  }
```

But , it's not taking opening square brace "["

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “escape the first /“?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find and replace the first character as below:

```
String data = "xxx-xxx-xxx - - [30/Oct/2020:22:39:54 +0000] --";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?=- - \\[)([^/]*)/")
                                 .matcher(data);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1\\\\/"));
}
```

This will output:

```
xxx-xxx-xxx - - [30\/Oct/2020:22:39:54 +0000] --
```

**Regex Pattern:** `(?=- - \[)([^/]*)/`

**Explanation:** Use [Postive Look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match `- -[`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below code it worked

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*)- - (.*)$").matcher(data);
                    if(matcher.find()){
                        String date = matcher.group(2).substring(1,3);
                        
                        System.out.println(date);
                    }
```

However I looking any other solution using regular expression